# Disable load examples in Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I have installed Apache Superset locally using Docker Compose. All of the pre-loaded examples were helpful at first, but I am wondering if there is a configuration setting to skip loading these examples.  I know that I could delete each example chart and dashboard individually, but I'm hoping there is a configuration setting somewhere that would disable loading examples. I've reviewed the documentation, but haven't seen such a setting.

https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/configuring-superset

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can disable the loading example by removing `SUPERSET_LOAD_EXAMPLES=yes` in the env file located at `docker/.env`. The environment is loaded from the `docker/.env` file for docker-compose.

```
 superset:
    env_file: docker/.env
    image: *superset-image
    container_name: superset_app
    command: ["/app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh", "app"]
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8088:8088
```

Comment: Or if you're using `docker-compose-non-dev.yml`, make this same removal in `./docker/.env-non-dev`.